# Converting a simple array into an object array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What is the easiest way to convert the former to the latter?

```
var simpleArray = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];


var objArray = [{ tag : 1}, { tag : 1},{ tag : 2}, { tag : 3},
                { tag : 5}, { tag : 8},{ tag : 13},{ tag : 21}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for underscore. You can do this pretty easily with vanilla javascript:

```js
var i, tag, main, simpleArray = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];

var complexArray = simpleArray.map(function(e) { return { tag: e }; });

main = document.getElementById('main');

for(i = 0; i < complexArray.length; i++) {
  tag = complexArray[i];
  main.innerHTML += '<div>tag: '+tag.tag+'</div>';
}
```

```html
<div id='main'></div>
```